Jest test isn't always successful
I use a Jest test to make sure that a certain behavior always works.

I wait for my app to load
Make a mock RTK query request (with msw)
Wait for requested data to get into the table in contentTableBody
Click a table row in contentTableBody to make a ItemDetails appear which shows some data passed with redux

Problem is that the test periodically fails due to not finding all of the table rows which leads me to believe there is some issue with asynchronisty of the code. How can I make sure that mock request always delivers all the data and the table is populated with it?
beforeEach(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("userId", "991d3a3a-6e71-4869-9861-2b897d7a9deb");
  localStorage.setItem(
    "default-customer-991d3a3a-6e71-4869-9861-2b897d7a9deb",
    JSON.stringify({
      customerId: "eu.33008274",
      customerNumber: "33008274",
      customerName: 'ООО "АДАМАНТ СПб"',
      street: "Глухоозерское ш.,д.12,лит.А,пом.8-Н,оф.2",
      postalCode: "Глухоозерское ш.,д.1",
      city: "г.Санкт-Петербург",
      state: "78",
      countryId: "RU",
    })
  );
});

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
}));

jest.mock("hooks/useIsComponentEnabled", () => ({
  useIsComponentEnabled: () => ({
    getIsComponentEnabled: () => jest.fn(true),
    isSuccess: true,
  }),
}));

it("renders table correctly", async () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <OrderList />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );

  await waitFor(async () => {
    const rows = await screen.findAllByRole("row");

    expect(rows.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(
      screen.getByText("67f9fdc8-ec0e-439a-9c4f-9a7307f4cd6e")
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  await userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole("row").at(-1));

  await waitFor(async () => {
    await expect(
      screen.getByTestId("itemDetailsContainer")
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

msw handler.js
export const handlers = [
  rest.get("http://localhost/api/v1/order-items/", (req, res, ctx) => {
    // successful response
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(testOrderData), ctx.delay());
  }),
  rest.get("http://localhost/api/v1/customers/", (req, res, ctx) => {
    // successful response
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(testCustomerData), ctx.delay(30));
  }),
  rest.get("http://localhost/api/v1/sites/", (req, res, ctx) => {
    // successful response
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(testSitesData), ctx.delay(30));
  }),
  rest.get("http://localhost/api/v1/users/", (req, res, ctx) => {
    // successful response
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(testUserData), ctx.delay(30));
  }),
  rest.get(
    "http://localhost/api/v1/users/991d3a3a-6e71-4869-9861-2b897d7a9deb/",
    (req, res, ctx) => {
      // successful response
      return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(testUserData), ctx.delay(30));
    }
  ),
];

OrderList.jsx
const OrderList = () => {
  const isDesktop = useIsDesktop();
  const { getIsComponentEnabled } = useIsComponentEnabled();
  const isComponentEnabled = getIsComponentEnabled("OrderList");
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  if (!isComponentEnabled) return <Navigate to="/overview" replace={true} />;

  return (
    <PageWrapper>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
        <PageHeading>{t("order.title")}</PageHeading>
        <OrderListOIButtons />
      </Box>
      <PageTypeProvider PageType="OrderList">
        <MainContentGridContainer>
          <LeftGrid>
            {isDesktop ? (
              <>
                <PageFilters />
                <ContentTable />
              </>
            ) : (
              <PageCard />
            )}
          </LeftGrid>
          {isDesktop && (
            <RightGrid>
              <ItemDetails />
            </RightGrid>
          )}
        </MainContentGridContainer>
      </PageTypeProvider>
    </PageWrapper>
  );
};

contentTableBody.jsx
const ContentTableBody = ({ paginationModel, handlePagination }) => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  const { isFetching, data, dataItem, columns, isInvoices } = useGetTableData();
  const { openDetailsCard, closeDetailsCard, setOrderId } = useDetailsCard();

  const {
    openSelectedCard,
    setDeliveriesToExport,
    closeSelectedCard,
    rowSelectionModel,
    setRowSelectionModel,
  } = useSelectedItemsCard(apiRef);

  const openOrderCard = ({ id }) => {
    setOrderId(id - 1);
    openDetailsCard();
  };

  const handlePageSize = ({ pageSize, page }) => {
    handlePagination({
      page: paginationModel.pageSize !== pageSize ? 0 : page,
      pageSize: pageSize,
    });
  };

  const handleRowSelection = (rowIds) => {
    setRowSelectionModel(rowIds);

    if (isInvoices) return;

    const deliveryIds = rowIds
      .filter((rowId) => data.results[rowId - 1].deliveries.length)
      .map((rowId) => data.results[rowId - 1].deliveries[0].deliveryId);

    setDeliveriesToExport(deliveryIds);

    if (rowIds.length) {
      openDetailsCard();
      openSelectedCard();
    }
    if (!rowIds.length) closeSelectedCard();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching) setRowSelectionModel([]);
  }, [isFetching, setRowSelectionModel]);

  useEffect(() => {
    closeDetailsCard();
  }, [closeDetailsCard]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) {
      apiRef.current.autosizeColumns({
        includeHeaders: true,
        includeOutliers: true,
      });
    }
  }, [isFetching, apiRef]);

  const rows = data?.results.map((item, index) => dataItem(item, index)) || [];

  return (
    <DataGrid
      autosizeOptions={{
        includeOutliers: true,
        includeHeaders: true,
      }}
      autosizeOnMount
      autoHeight
      checkboxSelection
      disableRowSelectionOnClick
      disableColumnMenu
      disableColumnResize
      rowCount={data?.count || 0}
      paginationMode="server"
      columnHeaderHeight={40}
      rows={rows}
      loading={isFetching}
      apiRef={apiRef}
      columns={columns}
      getRowHeight={() => "auto"}
      pageSizeOptions={rowsPerPage}
      onRowClick={openOrderCard}
      sortingOrder={["desc", "asc", null]}
      initialState={{
        pagination: {
          paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 10 },
        },
      }}
      paginationModel={paginationModel}
      onPaginationModelChange={handlePageSize}
      onRowSelectionModelChange={handleRowSelection}
      rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
      sx={OrderTableStyles}
      localeText={
        i18n.language === "ru"
          ? ruRU.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText
          : null
      }
    />
  );
};

ItemDetails.jsx
const ItemDetails = () => {
  const { isDetailsCardOpen } = useDetailsCard();
  const { isSelectedOpen } = useSelectedItemsCard();
  const { data, isInvoices } = useGetTableData();

  const currentOrderId = useSelector((state) => state.contentTable.orderId);
  const currentItemData = data?.results.length && data.results[currentOrderId];

  const initialView = isInvoices ? <PaymentSummary /> : <NoDataOverlay />;
  const content = isInvoices ? (
    <InvoiceDetails currentInvoiceData={currentItemData} />
  ) : (
    <OrderDetails currentOrderData={currentItemData} />
  );

  const renderDetails = () => {
    if (isSelectedOpen) return <PageCardOrderExport />;
    if (!currentItemData || !isDetailsCardOpen) return initialView;
    return content;
  };

  return (
    <Paper
      data-testid="itemDetailsContainer"
      elevation={4}
      sx={(theme) => ({
        padding: "16px",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        position: "sticky",
        top: "10px",
        overflowY: "auto",
        height: "600px",
        [theme.breakpoints.down("lgr")]: {
          display: !isDetailsCardOpen && "none",
          position: "fixed",
          top: "200px",
          right: "10px",
          minWidth: "300px",
          width: "40%",
          animation: `${slideCard} .2s`,
          zIndex: "6",
        },
      })}
    >
      {renderDetails()}
    </Paper>
  );
};


Are there possibly errors during the testing? I see you have stubbed out console.error so you might not see them if there were any. What does the OrderList component do that you are testing? Can you [edit] to include all relevant code you are working with? See [mcve]. Have you also considered that what you are doing here likely falls outside the confines of what normally considered a unit test? This is borderline integration testing. RTL can usually handle this grey area, but have you considered splitting/simplifying what you are trying to test?

I've added important component code and cleaned up jest code a bit. I remove console.error suppression and there are now errors in the console. OrderList is a page component which has  a structure of components. The most important are contentTableBody and ItemDetails. Click happens in contentTableBody and ItemDetails appears. That's why I need all this structure because these two components are far apart.

This is obviously just my opinion, but your unit test is doing way too much. If you just want to test that "renders table correctly" then reduce the testing to just the table component, mocking needed providers/etc obviously. As a general rule I recommend you start your unit tests from the smaller actual "units" of code, proving correctness. Then later on build up to more complex tests that compose your "units" together.

What are the errors? If they seem relevant to the issue then please [edit] to include them in the post.
